# Capture pdf cover as photo

Tags: jquery, pdf, plugins, web, image

I am a new developer on web application.

Now I am doing an upload file (PDF) to my server, and I need a picture of the cover of the PDF that user uploaded.

I try to find jquery plug-in for that.

Do you know any relevant JQuery plug-in or technique to do so??

Regard,

Comment: I'm guessing you'll probably have to use a server side library to render the first page as an image and then use that image (trivial).  The hard part is the server side part.

Comment: Thank lucuma, Aren't there any client technique to do so? can't Jquery help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to have to do this server side using something like PHP. PHP has PDF and Image libraries that will allow you to do this. I would instead search for that rather than jQuery

Comment: Thank, What i am concern is the server job might be too heavy when MANY users send the queries to the server ..

Comment: You could possibly look at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js to see if you can adapt it to display the first page only although I'd agree with Ronnie that you'd probably be better off doing it on the server side.

Comment: I am not entirely sure doing this through javascript is possible. I found this on google: http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/ and looks like he made the ability to generate PDFs through javscript. You may be able to generate the first page and just display that. edit::I see lucuma had the same idea and beat me to it

Comment: What do you guys think about this 
http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=230074

Comment: If you're worried about load, use a queuing system like Gearman - the queue then is carried out either serially (i.e. setting up one worker task) or in limited parallel (setting up n>1 worker tasks). It's trivial to set up in PHP, so long as you're not on a shared host.